# SumIf formula with multiple columns or criterias

Tags: excel, google-sheets, sum, formula

Happy Friday,

I need help with a formula.

I want `C30:C35` to be the sum of `D2:D10` IF the text in `B2:B10` Matches the text in `A30:A35`

So if A30 says "Apples" and B3 and B4 also say "Apples" it would sum up the total numbers in D3 and D4 to appear in C30 (where I will input the formula)

I tried a few sumifs I found online but keep getting errors

Comment: `=SUMIFS($D$2:$D$10,$B$2:$B$10,A30)` then copy drag down.

Comment: @ScottCraner why not write it as an answer?